# What's the correct Spanish word to mean "as" in this context

Tags: traducción

Words like "as" have many definitions, so I'm having difficulty finding the Spanish word that would make sense in this sense:

> "Where are you going?" John asked as Mary grabbed her keys.

I first tried to find a direct translation of *as*, and got *como*. But that didn't sound quite right. So I tried *while* and got *mientras* but I don't think that's quite right either; the two events don't happen exactly simultaneously. She starts to pick up the keys and that's when he asks; it probably takes less time for her to pick up the keys than for him to finish his question, so he's still talking when she's done. The same applies to *during*, which I tried next (and got *durante*). Not quite right for similar reasons to *while*.

So I'm just not quite sure what Spanish word fits here. I have a feeling that there's perhaps an idiomatic construction for situations like these, since *as* is such a versatile word in English; I understand why a direct translation might be unlikely. So, can anyone help me out here? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mientras (que)` sounds right for me, as the use of `as` in your phrase makes me think Mary's grabbing her keys while John is asking. Also another translation that comes to my mind is `al momento/instante/tiempo que` or `en tanto que` which would be more "at the same time" than `mientras`. Also I think `durante` would not make much sense here. Some translations I'd use:

- "¿A dónde vas?" Pregunto John mientras (que) Mary tomaba sus llaves
- "¿A dónde vas?" Pregunto John al momento que Mary tomaba sus llaves
- "¿A dónde vas?" Pregunto John al instante que Mary tomaba sus llaves
- "¿A dónde vas?" Pregunto John al tiempo que Mary tomaba sus llaves
- "¿A dónde vas?" Pregunto John en tanto que Mary tomaba sus llaves

Comment: Thanks again for the helpful answer! :) I understand all the other examples, but with is the difference between using *mientras* by itself vs. *mientras que*? Thank you!

Comment: "cuando" also works here: `Preguntó John cuando Mary tomaba sus llaves` It is also relevant to notice `Preguntó` needs accent (tilde) otherwise it would say: `..going? I ask John as Mary..` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @WendiKidd You're welcome, and I'd say the meaning of both ways is the same

Answer (score 4):

In this case, since John's action is a consequence of Mary's, I would vary the construction in Spanish slightly:

> "¿A dónde vas?", preguntó John cuando Mary cogió las llaves.

*Mientras* can be a correct word, but it emphasises the simultaneous nature of both actions, not the consequential relation.

Notice that I have used *cogió* and not *cogía*. In this case, the verb tense is very important. If I use *cogía*, I am once again emphasising the simultaneity and not the consequence. The way I write it, both actions happen more or less at the same time too, but it is clear that John's starts after Mary's.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; very insightful! I hadn't considered *cuando*, but I like the way you've used it here. It sounds right in my head, and seems most similar to the original *as* :) Thanks! (+1 :))

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [@darkajax](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4082/106) for the most part, and he gives several viable options for this specific context. I just wanted to add a common translation for "as" in other contexts: "a medida que".

> **As** her grandchildren grew taller, Grandma got shorter.
>
> **A medida que** sus nietos crecían más altos, la abu se hacía más baja.

"A medida que" expresses a meaning similar to "mientras que", but, as is the case with "as" and "while", they're used in slightly different contexts.